# C# WPF add control in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I want to add some controls in a `DataGrid`.

I have the XML code:

```
<DataGrid Name="dgCreateOperationsData" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="214" Margin="2,170,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="775" FontWeight="Bold" HeadersVisibility="None" SelectionMode="Single" Background="White"  CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" ColumnWidth="100"/>
```

and the following code:

```
OperationEntry opEntry = new OperationEntry();
opEntry.OperationName = new ComboBox() { Width = 50, ItemsSource = _operationList};
opEntry.Time = new TextBox() { Width = 50, Text = "" };
opEntry.Flow = new TextBox() { Width = 50, Text = "" };
opEntry.SysSpeed = new TextBox() { Width = 50, Text = "" };
opEntry.Pressure = new TextBox() { Width = 50, Text = "" };
opEntry.Torque = new TextBox() { Width = 50, Text = "" };
opEntry.Power = new TextBox() { Width = 50, Text = "" };
opEntry.Current = new TextBox() { Width = 50, Text = "" };

_operationEntryList.Add(opEntry);
dgCreateOperationsData.ItemsSource = _operationEntryList;
```

The problem is the controls are showing but have the control type visible, till i double-click it ( see image )

[image]

Why is this happening? And how to remove these labels ??

Comment: Why are you not using Xaml to add columns in `DataGrid`? and what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Looks like you need to create a `DataTemplate`

Comment: @sham there will be a button, and on click of that button I want to append this new row. This can be done any number of times. That's why I'm doing this in code. I don't know if this can be done in xml

Comment: So you want to add new row with data to DataGrid. Is that correct?

Comment: @sham, yeah...a row with controls ( combobox and textbox)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code. You need to work on it to finalize the functionality.
One record is added through code and to add more records, you just need to press enter in last row. It will automatically add the record to collection and you can do whatever you wish to with the data.

View -

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding CountryList}" BorderThickness="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Country Name" Binding="{Binding CountryName}"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="City Name"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

ViewModel -

```
    public ObservableCollection<CountryData> CountryList { get; set; }

        CountryList = new ObservableCollection<CountryData>();
        CountryList.Add(new CountryData { CountryName = "India" });
```

Comment: thanks, but my question is for row containing controls. Normal text is working just fine

Comment: All of these rows are editable on click inside of `Datagrid cell`.

Answer (score 0):

You could define `DataGridTemplateColumns` with `CellTemplates`:

```
...
dgCreateOperationsData.ItemsSource = _operationEntryList;
dgCreateOperationsData.AutoGeneratingColumn += (s, e) =>
{
    FrameworkElementFactory fe = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(ContentControl));
    fe.SetBinding(ContentControl.ContentProperty, new Binding(e.PropertyName));
    e.Column = new DataGridTemplateColumn()
    {
        CellTemplate = new DataTemplate() { VisualTree = fe }
    };
};
```